# How to detect "playing" application from IDE rather than actual application start?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Application_Start() works the first time the app starts. However, with asp.net mvc the application continues to run as you start and stop and start and stop it from the IDE (so long as it doesn't get recompiled or app pool otherwise recycled).

Is there a way I could basically just detect if the play button was hit from the IDE?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?  Rather than trying to detect application startup, there may be a technique to do whatever it is that you want to do another way.

Comment: Just trying to figure out ways to be more efficient with troubleshooting. So like every time I start the app I would like it run a method that resets some stuff. But as I'm typing this I'm realizing I could prolly just set it to go to a test page that would do that and then redirect me automatically.